# Alerts Triggered are not on the shapes plotted

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, indicator

I have setup the same alertcondition() as in my plotshape() , but the alert doesnt trigger at the time the shape is plotted on the chart.

what i have done so far ?
experimented with selecting all alert types (even after bar close) none seem to work,
have tried to do add title within plotshape and using it to trigger alert setting conditions in the create alert box.

```
plotshape(series=buySignal, title="newtitle", text="BUY",style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.normal)
```

nothing seems to work.

here is the code:-

```
isLong = false
isLong := nz(isLong[1], false)

isShort = false
isShort := nz(isShort[1], false)


buySignal = not isLong and (godlong1 or godlong2 or godlong3 or godlong4 or godlong5)


sellSignal= not isShort and (godshort1 or godshort2 or godshort3 or godshort4 or godshort5)

if (buySignal)
    isLong := true
    isShort := false

if (sellSignal)
    isLong := false
    isShort := true

plotshape(series=buySignal, text="BUY",style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.normal)
plotshape(series=sellSignal, text="SELL", style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.normal)


alertcondition(buySignal, title='BUY LONG', message='Bulls Are Fast!!!')
alertcondition(sellSignal, title='SELL SHORT', message='Bears Are Slow!!!')
```

can someone please help me with this , unable to figure the solution .

Thanks a lot in advance

Regards!

Comment: Chart type? Symbol/Timeframe?

Comment: chart type= candles
symbol=xbtusd
tf=1min

Comment: What do you mean by "the alert doesn't trigger at the time the shape is plotted on the chart"? What's your expectation? If your alert is configured to trigger "Once Per Bar", a few seconds delay is normal between the appearance of the shape (which will happen at the beginning of the realtime bar) and the alert.